# Overriding html.js not working in GatsbyJS

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I'm following the [directions here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/) on Gatsby's website to customize the `<head>` tag. I want to add Modernizr and Google's WebFont libraries. I copied `.cache/default-html.js` and put it in `src/html.js`, and then I added the script tags the libraries, but they aren't showing up on my localhost:8000.

Is there some Gatsby cache that needs cleared when trying to do a custom `html.js`? Or is there another way to add these to the `<head>` tag?

EDIT: It turns out I was trying to put a `<script></script>` tag in the JSX of the html.js.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your edit?  The docs and [this issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3083) seem to pretty clearly state that simply pasting a script tag into the body should work, but it definitely does not...  Even using dangerouslySetInnerHTML to add the script content does not work.  I am restarting the development server and still not seeing my script tag in the document.  FWIW, I'm just trying to add a Google Analytics script to the body...

Comment: I believe I must have been making some syntax error, as I tried it in a blank project and it worked there, and then I re-tried in my project and it suddenly worked. Maybe try it in a fresh project and you'll see something?

Answer (score 3):

Use [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) to customize the `<head>` tag. Check out their documentation for more examples.

```
import React from "react";
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

class Application extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <div className="application">
            <Helmet>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <title>My Title</title>
                <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/example" />
            </Helmet>
            ...
        </div>
    );
  }
};
```

**install with:**
`npm i --save gatsby-plugin-react-helmet react-helmet`

**update gatsby-config.js:**
`plugins: ['gatsby-plugin-react-helmet']`

For a working example, create a new build with `gatsby new gatsby-site` and 
have look at the  component in `src/layouts/index.js`

```
 <Helmet
      title="Gatsby Default Starter"
      meta={[
        { name: 'description', content: 'Sample' },
        { name: 'keywords', content: 'sample, something' },
      ]}
    />
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution, but it looks like from the Gatsby docs, they seem to imply a non-dynamic update (like adding a web font to the whole site) should go in `html.js`: _"If you want to dynamically update your <head> we recommend using React Helmet"_ Can you get `html.js` to work for you?

Comment: Yes `html.js` works for me. You aren't seeing changes reflected in your `<head>` on localhost? Forgot to mention, for google webfonts, it's cleaner to just use this plugin: https://github.com/didierfranc/gatsby-plugin-google-fonts

Comment: No, changes aren't showing up in my `<head>` on localhost. Thanks for the tip on google-fonts!

Comment: Hmm did you copy the contents of `.cache/default-html.js` and create a new file named `html.js` in your project's `src` folder? Make a change to the `<head>` in that new file and then fire up `gatsby develop` you should see the change in dev tools

Comment: I tried it on another demo gatsby project and it worked there, and then I retried it on my project and it worked. Sigh. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hello Eric, I have tried the same and it actually worked in Develop but when i build it i get a completely different result when i deploy to AWS cloudfront. I get two instances of the same page in a single index page.